# KendoUI Grid Set Modal Validation Max to the Value of Other Column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following modal:

```
...
quantity: {
             type: 'number',
             validation: {
                min: 0
             }
          }
...
```

In my grid you can click to inline edit a value. What I would like to do is, is when the quantity field is selected and is ready for the user to start inputting numbers, I want the max possible value to be set to the value of another column that was returned to my grid e.g. `quantityMax`.

`quantityMax` will be different for each row in my grid.

How can I do this? The handler for an input change is:

```
$('#salesGrid').on('change', '.k-input', function(){
  handleChange()
})

function handleChange()
{
  sGrid.dataSource.sync(); // Write changes.
  sGrid.dataSource.read(); // Read updated grid.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it using an editor function for `quantity` field. This is as easy as:

```
columns   : [
    // Other columns definition
    { field: "quantityMax", title: "Max", width: 50 },
    {
        width : 50,
        title : "Quantity",
        field : "quantity",
        editor: function (container, options) {
            // create an input element
            var input = $("<input name='" + options.field + "'/>");
            // append it to the container
            input.appendTo(container);
            // initialize a Kendo UI numeric text box and set max value
            input.kendoNumericTextBox({
                max: options.model.quantityMax
            });
        }
    }
],
```

What I do is when KendoUI enters in edition mode I generate an input field and set `max` to the value of `quantityMax` and I get it from `options.model`.

For a working example in JSFiddle click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/fNH8h/)

Comment: Cool, if I don't want the max column to show what is the parameter to hide the column?

Comment: Just remove `{ field: "quantityMax", title: "Max", width: 50 },` You don't have to display all columns in your model.

Comment: How would you do this using the mvc grid? Is it possible?